# jQuery find exact HTML content

Tags: jquery

I am using the following script to find all h1 elements, within a parent ID container that will fit a curtain criteria...

```
$('#cpcompheader h1').html("&nbsp;").remove();
```

That script is finding any scenario, such as....

```
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
<h1>&nbsp; one two</h1>
<h1>&nbsp; the sun is up</h1>
<h1>&nbsp; etc...</h1>
```

But I only want to find all instances of...

```
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
```

So how should I modify my code?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try finding all the h1 tags and then checking if they contain a certain value.

```
$('#yourParent h1').each(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "&nbsp;"){
        // magic
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not include the if check right in the selector? Also, your string won't match when `&nbsp;` isn't the only content. You'd need a regex, probably.

Comment: I suppose you could include the `if` statement in the selectors. And regarding the content, I was under the impression he wants to grab elements that only match a single `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove all h1s that contains an nbsp you can try something like this:
[removing all elements that contains nbsp](http://jsfiddle.net/26TJn/)

```
$("h1").each(function() {
if ($(this).html().indexOf("&nbsp;") != -1) {
    $(this).remove();
}
});
```

Now if you want to remove elements that matches exactly an nbsp just modify it as this: [modified version](http://jsfiddle.net/26TJn/2/)

```
$("h1").each(function() {
    if ($(this).html() === "&nbsp;") {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like:

```
$('h1:contains(&nbsp;)');
```

or if you want the exact match:

```
$('h1').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === "&nbsp;"; });
```

you could also look at the contains selector documentation: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: That wouldn't match elements that contain only the specified value though, it would include any h1's that have &nbsp;. It depends what OP wants.

Comment: Does `contains()` find HTML entities?

Comment: @isherwood I don't think so. I have edited the answer to add exact string matching :)

Comment: Vasil, I tried your code but it didn't work for me. I don't think you can use text() for **&nbsp;** detection...its html.

Comment: Using contains wont work because it transforms &nbsp; into text.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myRegEx = new RegExp('^&nbsp;\s');    

$('#myDiv h1').each(function() {
    var myText = $(this).text();

    if (myText.match(myRegEx) ) { ... }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could filter your element using regex, and then remove it if dont have any value

```
$('h1').each(function(){
  var filtered = $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&nbsp;/gi,''));     
  if($(filtered).html() === ''){
    $(filtered).remove();
  }
});
```

[here a demo](http://jsbin.com/gebosagi/1/edit)